# Cant get PackageInstaller.uninstall working

Tags: java, android, packageinstaller

My app has device admin privilege but yet I'm unable to uninstall the app using packageinstaller. When my code runs it didn't throw any error yet, app I'm trying to uninstall stays there. Any idea what could be wrong? Or how to investigate the issue deeper?

```
            String appPackage = "juanito.ovik.moviefinder2";
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),getActivity().getClass());
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
            PackageInstaller mPackageInstaller = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
            mPackageInstaller.uninstall(appPackage, sender.getIntentSender());
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding app "device owner" permision through ADB command